# Facebook Messenger Platform - Webhook Subscription

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have followed the steps to setup the Facebook Messenger platform.  The verification GET web hook request work perfectly, as does the subscribe but when I submit the chat I keep getting the follow Developer Alert:

Hi Norah,
We've noticed that your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://{domain}/v1/webhook has not been accepting updates for at least 16 minutes. Please verify that your callback server is functioning so you may continue to receive updates. If you need to update your callback URL, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#webhook_setup

If your callback URL continues to fail to accept updates for 8 hours straight, we will disable your subscription. To reactivate the subscription, make a POST request with the same parameters, and it will be reactivated.

My post request works through POSTMAN.

Please can someone help me!  This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have logs on your server for that post requests?
Facebook requires you to return status code 200 for the post request, so they know that you successfully received it. When they havent, they try it again and if that still fails after several times, they will give you this alert.
Maybe facebook uses another content-type or message content than you used with postman.
Your server logs should give you more insights about that.

Comment: When or how does the post happen?  Are they the actual subscribed events, eg message received?  Or are they periodic scheduled tasks done by Facebook to check whether my callback is alive?

Comment: there is just one initial get for verification to check if your server is alive. after that its a callback event for every message received at a subscribed page. if they dont succeed, facebook gets alarmed (and they will retry a few times)..but there are no additional alive-checking post request.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what [Webhook events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#setup_webhook) that you have subscribed for a page, there will be callbacks for those events, and more, on the url you have specified in the Web Hook set up.

If you had subscribed to the `message_deliveries` event, every time a message is sent, whether from a user to your page or from your page to a user, there is a, maybe more, calllback with a `Message Delivered` json object. The [Webhook Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#message_delivery) has an example of the `Message Delivered` json object, but no specification or explanation on what the fields mean.

Occasionally I find that an undocumented `Read` callback is received, sometimes. The undocumented json data for this is like:

```
{"object":"page",
 "entry":[
  {
    "id":"1722858134648129",
    "time":1465407550812,
    "messaging":[
    {
      "sender":{"id":"1131485883560113"},
      "recipient":{"id":"1722858134642218"},
      "timestamp":1465407550868,
      "read":
      {
        "watermark":1465407548057,
        "seq":428
      }}]}]}
```

**Essentially, you must code your callback to handle ALL types of json data *gracefully*, including unknowns**, even though you may not be ready to process them further. For those that you are not ready to handle or uninterested in, return nothing with Http status code 204 (in fact every callback should return 204 as the type is `void`).

If you handle only those types of json data you are interested in, any unexpected json data will most likely raise an exception in whatever language your web callback code is written in and result in a 500 server error returned to Facebook. It is this 500 error that is causing Facebook to make that complaint in your question.