# Messenger Platform: Webhook failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My question is kinda like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885850/facebook-messenger-platform-webhook-subscription).

> Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://{domain}/bot has not been accepting updates for at least 2 days. Please verify that your callback server is functioning. Visit our reference documentation to learn how to update your callback URL.
>
> If your callback URL is still failing after 12 hours your subscription will be disabled. To reactivate, just make a POST request with the same parameters or visit the Webhooks tab in the app dashboard.

However, I am very sure that I've returned status 200 to every request, here is part of my code:

```
router.post("/bot", (req, res) => {
    Promise.map(req.body["entry"], eachEntry => {
        return Promise.map(eachEntry["messaging"], eachMessage => {
           // some postback and quick_replies handling, send messages...
        });
    })
    .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

I only subscribed events like `messages`, `messaging_postbacks` , `message_deliveries`. I think even there are something I didn't handle, these requests will get status 200 eventually.

But what I don't understand is, every time I received the webhook failing alert, I didn't see errors or anything which wasn't returned as status 200 in the log.

I also tried change `res.sendStatus(200)` to `res.end()` or `res.status(200).end()` but it didn't help neither.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried making a post to your endpoint using postman?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works. In fact, it's already public and some friends have used it.

Comment: I mean some friends have used this bot for a while. Somehow I can't edit my comment...

Comment: You can try sending the response status outside the promise. I mean, you don't need to wait for the promise to return the response status, you will always send 200.

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Yeah, I was thinking about that. But I use [sender actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions) in the commented area.

I tried to move res.sendStatus(200) to the top, but the sender action will be...some kind of weird. It shows and then disappears. Then it shows again.

I guess I am just too picky... but I also don't think it's the root of problem. :(

Comment: It's a little complicated to figured out the issue without know what's going on in your `Promise.map` logic but is seems like your code is not returning rejected promises or it's not returning promises so your first `Promise.map` always return a resolved promise, or it's sending the response but it's taking too long to process all entries. As facebook needs the response as fast as possible I would send the response before processing the message, in this way you won't receive any timeout error from facebook.

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Thanks for your reply, I decided to move res.sendStatus(200) to the top again for days and see how it goes.

Comment: Well, 2 days after. No one uses bot during these 2 days. When I tried to send some messages, it works. And then Webhook alerts show up. I don't even know why.

Comment: Well I just found [this issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/594288957423128/). I think it's related, if anyone also encountered this issue can subscribe it. Thanks @AndrésAndrade

Comment: Can you create an answer with the issue? I think it would be helpful if anyone else is facing this issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been dealing with this issue for the past 2 weeks and it was driving me crazy as I knew that all is working well on our server and the webhook response was always 200 OK...

So I found this thread: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/594288957423128/ ... and apparently a lot of people are having this issue. Turns out it was a fault on the Messenger Platform side.

Here is what one from the facebook team wrote:

> Hi Eugene and others,
>
> We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed next Tuesday. Stay tuned.
>
> Shireesh
> 5 hours ago · (4 Jan 2017)

So fingers crossed... the issue should be resolved soon! ;)